# Using fetch method inside Kendo UI grid.template

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

How to return value from `.fetch()` method inside `grid.template` ?

```
$("#grid-single-user-groups").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: assignedUsersDataSource,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
          {
            field: "UserID", width: "100%",
            editor: userDropDownEditor,
            template: function(userID) {
              //here I can return everything, and its visible in grid cell
              //return "BAR"
              allUsersDataSource.fetch(function() {
                //Here everything is UNDEFINED
                return "FOO";
                var data = this.data();
                console.log(data.length);
                for (var idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                  console.log(data.length); //show right length
                  console.log(data[idx].UserName);// //show right UserName
                  if (data[idx].UserNameID === userID.UserID) {
                    return userID.Login; //UNDEFINED
                    //return "foo"; //UNDEFINED
                  }



              })
```

edit:

`allUsersDataSource` is Kendo DataSource:

```
  var allUsersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: API_URL + "frank/getusers",
        dataType: "json"
      }
    },
  });
```

results JSON:

```
[{"UserNameID":"2","UserName":"foo","Surname":"foo2","Login":"foo3","GroupName":"admin"},]
```

edit2:

trying with read() function instead od fetch, with below code:

```
    template: function(userID) {
      allUsersDataSource.read().then(function() {
        var view = allUsersDataSource.view();
        console.log(view[0].Login)// displays right Login
        return view[0].Login; // displays "undefined" in grid cell
      });
    }
```

edit3:
 My entire code where I whant to use DropDown inside Grid cell:

```
  var allUsersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: API_URL + "frank/getusers",
        dataType: "json"
      }
    },
  });

  allUsersDataSource.fetch(function() {
    allUsers = allUsersDataSource.data();
  })

  var assignedUsersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read:{
        url: API_URL+"frank/getassignedusers/"+documentId,
        dataType: "json"
      },
      create: {
        type: "POST",
        url: API_URL+"frank/addusertodocument",
        dataType: "json"
      },
      destroy:{
        type: "POST",
        url: API_URL+"frank/removeuserdocument",
        dataType: "json"
      },
    },
    pageSize: 4,
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          UserName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
          Surname: { editable: false, nullable: true },
          UserID: { field: "UserID", defaultValue: 1 },
          GroupName: { editable: false, nullable: true },
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $("\#grid-single-user-groups").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: assignedUsersDataSource,
    filterable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
      {
        field: "UserID", width: "100%",
        editor: userDropDownEditor,
        title: "Agent",
        template: function(userID) {
            for (var idx = 0, length = allUsers.length; idx < length; idx++) {
              if (allUsers[idx].UserNameID === userID.UserID) {
                return userID.Login;
              }
            }
        }
      },
      { command: "destroy" }
    ],
    editable: true,
    remove: function(e) {
      console.log("Removing", e.model.name);
    }
  });

  function userDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "Login",
      dataValueField: "UserNameID",
      filter: "contains",
      dataSource: allUsersDataSource
    })
  }
```

JSON DataSources - assignedUsersDataSource:

```
[{"UserID":"198","UserName":"Paw","Surname":"yui","Login":"ddz","GroupName":"ddd"},...]
```

JSON DataSources - allUsersDataSource:

```
[{"UserNameID":"198","UserName":"Paw","Surname":"yui","Login":"ddz","GroupName":"ddd"},...]
```

edit4:
corrected sample datasource:

```
   var assignedUsersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: [{"UserID":"198","UserName":"Paw","Surname":"Mu","Login":"pc","GroupName":"ad"}]
    });

     var allUsers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: [{"UserNameID":"198","UserName":"Paw","Surname":"Mu","Login":"pc","GroupName":"ad"},{"UserNameID":"199","UserName":"Jakub","Surname":"Ch","Login":"jc","GroupName":"ki"}]
    });
```

Comment: what is the allUsersDataSource? how is it configured? have you looked at this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/fetch for further assistance with fetch.

Comment: @DavidShorthose edited main post

Comment: why fetch rather than read the data? I suspect you need to follow the example to track the end of the fetch request so that the code continues with the data.

Comment: @DavidShorthose tried with read function with same results as edit2 in main post

Comment: is this what you are after: http://dojo.telerik.com/INukUVoT

Comment: @DavidShorthose There is one problem with this example. Please copy corrected datasources from main post "edit4" and paste to Your example. Problem is that when you choose  new item from dropdown and click mouse outside dropdown it will display the first item. Also when You chose "Add new record" it will display "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to avoid cluttering up the comments here is a possible answer to your problem:

http://dojo.telerik.com/INukUVoT/4

If you now select the item from the dropdown it is changing the id as it retains the last selected item in the selection when you go in and out of it. The reason the name stays the same is a simple one. It's looking in the wrong place for the value to display.

You are simply doing the following:

Look at all the values in the allusers store and then if i get a match of id's just show the value in the model's Login value rather than the value that was found in the data item in the Login.

So you are currently going through a needs loop. you literally could change your template to:

`template: "#=data.Login#"` rather than having to loop around.

what you seemingly want to do is have one column which is a user object or defined as an id either way will work as you can see in my new examples.

the first grid is binding the UserID property to the grid and then presenting back the value from the dropdown's datasource (you need to ensure that you set the valuePrimitive property to true so it binds only the value and not the object.

the second grid binds the full object and just so you see what is being bound i am stingify'ing the object and putting that into the grid.

Comment: If You like, please take a look at my new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063163/how-to-force-evoke-datasource-parametermap-after-grid-data-changed-in-kendo-ui-g where is discribed problem about datasource of grid that did not react to changes of its dropdown cell.